# installed Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition, but none of .NET classes are available

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

For instance,

I was trying to use

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com/");
```

But get an error message!

I am trying to use the WebRequest .NET framework class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f.aspx

How can I enable .NET? Is something wrong with my installation?

Comment: Can you indicate what error message you get?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe put `Imports System.Net` at the top of class?